# why is my loading spinner on mobile not loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

on my mac, the loading spinner works but on my phone when I upload the image the spinner does not spin and lags.

aim: when a user on mobile uploads a photo then clicks the continue button (that turns into a spinner) the spinner starts spinning

problem: I presume due to the website processing the image the mobile does not have enough power to also load the spinner.

my css for spinner is:

```
.active-animate {
    font-size: 0;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border-left-color: transparent;
    animation: rotate 1.18s ease 0.2s infinite;
}
@keyframes rotate {
    from {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
```

then my js code is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.button-animate').click(function() {
        $(this).addClass('active-animate');
    });
});
```

if you need any more code or anything else just ask.
thanks

Comment: You must have another problem elsewhere not in the code you provided. What you provided currently works. https://jsfiddle.net/3n20pc4s/1/

Comment: Please provide browser info also.

Comment: @RishabhAnand what exactly do you want the link to website?

Comment: @cssyphus how would this help all i want is for spinner circle to spin on mobile view

Comment: @fharris just need what browsers you're testing on, just in case.

Comment: make something which always shows it to test if it works then it might just be jitter because other animationframes/repaints etc are taking precedence or your phone is simply slow. dep on your phones browser and version it might not be supported: https://caniuse.com/?search=%40keyframes